# How to use material ui date range picker - selectonly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, daterangepicker

I am trying to add material ui date range picker to add start date and end date.How to customise the material ui date range picker to User will only select the date from Date picker but will not be able to change the date manually.

```
...
import { DateRangePicker, LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers-pro";

...
<DateRangePicker
        readOnly={readOnly}
       
        value={props.value ?? [new Date(), new Date()]}
        onChange={(newValue) => props.handleChange(newValue)}
        renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
          
            <div className={styles.inputGroup}>
              <div className={styles.fieldBox}>
                <TextField
                  {...startProps}
                  helperText={props.error?.message ?? props.error[0]?.message}
                  label=""
                  className={`textfield ${styles.borderLeftRadius}`}
                  placeholder={startPlaceholder}
                  error={props.error?.message || props.error[1] ? true : false}
                  name={startDateName}
                  InputProps={{
                    readOnly: readOnly,
                  }}
                />
                <span className={styles.iconBox}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCalendarWeek} size="1x" />
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.date_divider}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight} size="xs" />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.fieldBox}>
                <TextField
                  {...endProps}
                  label=""
                  error={props.error?.message || props.error[1] ? true : false}
                  helperText={props.error?.message ?? props.error[1]?.message}
                  className={`textfield ${styles.borderRightRadius}`}
                  placeholder={endPlaceholder}
                  name={endDateName}
                  InputProps={{
                    readOnly: readOnly,
                  }}
                />
                <span className={styles.iconBox}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCalendarWeek} size="1x" />
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      />
```

Comment: is it possible to disable the inputs?

Comment: when disabled/ redonly=true the text fields then can,t select the dates from calendar

Comment: try bind OpenPickerButtonProps to the onclick of the entire component while disable the inputs?